# JS: awaited resolved promises come back wrapped in a promise that I cannot access

Tags: javascript

I am ultimately pushing unresolved promises to be values of an object and then awaiting those to recall later:

```
let names = ["aaron", "bob", "john", "aaron"];
let allNames = {};
```

// just setting up my object with names as the key

```
names.forEach(name => {
   if (!allNames[name]) {
         allNames[name] = null;
   }
});
```

//iterating through and running async requests in parallel and storing the unresolved promises as the object value

```
let allDataForNamedPerson;

for (const [x] of names) {
   if (!allNames[name]) {
       allDataForNamesPerson = this.getNameData(name)// async api call
        
       allNames[name] = allDataForNamesPerson // storing the promise
   }
}
```

then I await until all these have resolves;

```
    await Promise.all([...Object.values(this.allNames)]);
```

my problem is that when I go to looking up one of the resolved values from the object, for example:

`allNames["john"]` , the value in console an Object wrapped in a promise:

```
promise {
   salary: 41992,
   position: clerk
}
```

so I cannot access it via `allNames["john"].salary` -- that comes back as undefined.   What I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like is a simple async await issue? i..e. you have not resolved the promise.

Comment: I do have `await Promise.all([...Object.values(this.allNames)]);` with the accompanying top level `async` though

Comment: awaiting a promise doesn't magically change any location containing it to a non-promise

Comment: @ASDFGerte to confirm I am awaiting them, I logged `[...Object.values(this.allNames)]` before I awaited Promise.all and got back in console: `[ Promise { <pending> } ]`.  I then logged it after the Promise.all and got back: `[ Promise { { salary: 41992, position: "clerk" } } ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` doesn't replace promises with their values. If you want to work with the values, you have to grab them yourself:

```js
  const resolvedValues = await Promise.all([...Object.values(this.allNames)]);
```

and then `resolvedValues[someIndex]` gives you unwrapped data.

Using bare `await` only guarantees that a given promise is settled in the code after the `await` line but the values are still wrapped.

Comment: I see, thanks.  Is there anyway to await them and keep them associated with the object key they are in?

Comment: There isn't a straightforward way to `await` an associative array (object). You need to convert it to a standard array first using e.g. `Object.entries`.